# Display input file as background?

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering how is it possible to display a file input within the HTML document.

`<input type="file">` Lets me to pick an image file, but I'm really not sure about how I can use it within the existing HTML structure? I want to display the picked image within the document with an `html/css` only workaround. This is just for offline use / learning purposes.

Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried, what kind of serverside language are you using? What is considered an 'input file'?

Comment: I'm just trying to achieve this for offline use.

Comment: So, nothing. Looking for an html/css based solution

Comment: "input file" is image -- sorry (I'll edit the post now)

Comment: Check my answer for explanation on why you cant do that.

Comment: @Manish Yes, I did - that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a file from an `input` with plain `HTML`/`CSS` to a background won't be possible. You'll need to make use of Javascript in this case. I'd suggest using ActiveX, here's the idea:

```
var oFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var oCTF = oFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\\myimage.jpg", true);
oCTF.write(document.getElementById("Data").value);
oCTF.Close();
```

You'd need to handle this in a function, that's gonna be triggered by `onclick=` or something similar on your submit.

Note: I haven't tested this bit, since I'm at work. Though you'd need to change it to your needs anyway.

Comment: "my image.jpg" - how is this related to the input file?

Comment: I hadn't seen your edit at that time. That's why I added the Edit to my answer.

Comment: I see - how is this possible with JS, then?

Comment: I've edited my answer Zettam.

Answer (score 2):

You cant. You're uploading an image on a pre-loaded page. DOM is already build. If you want to change the DOM after client action you need to use some client side code.
Use Jquery.css() method to change body:background

@EDIT: Also, in order for that file to be created you need to place that input inside a form and submit.

@EDIT2: When you submit the html form an action will be triggered (a http request will be make to the value of action attibute of form element, can be GET or POST). 
You can either set this value or leave it blank and most browsers will make request to the same page you're on. The thing is, the file is sent to the server and the page is loaded again but you lost all info about the file.

If what you want is to let the users send the background file you can use a server side language too to process the data from the file. Place the action to a php function that changes the name of the file to "background.jpg" for example an place that name at the body:background

Comment: Whoa, this is a classic example of overusing `Jquery` when not necessary. Why would you use such a huge library when some very simple Javascript would suffice?

Comment: There is actually no problem using JQuery but i get the point.

Comment: Well, depends on the rest of the application whether to use Jquery or stick to regular Javascript I guess. What I'm trying to say is, consider whether you need Jquery before using it ;)

Comment: You never need Jquery, you just use is cause it already has the code done.

Comment: I can't see why not to use jquery. 93KB (just checked comressed 1.9.1) is too much? Even if you will use 1% of it, is it not pre optimisation? :)

Comment: And improved scalability. And easier to manage for those that don't understand javascript. Oh, and error free many times.

Comment: Well understanding Jquery without understanding Javascript is a shame if you ask me, since Jquery is a framework for Javascript.

Comment: Jquery is not a framework, it is a lib. A lib is something you call, a framwework is something that calls you. 
Also there isnt much to understand in Jquery, that's why its ideal for people that just dont care about understanding this kind of things. And you can see that a person dont care when it doesnt even know what DOM is and want to change it around.